# Can interpolation be done on print output and in the middle of the output, is it possible to use gets in Ruby? (expecting reply from Ruby folks)

Tags: ruby

```
print """Input 1: (here I want *gets* to have some input)
Input 2: 
"""
```

is it possible to get input in the middle of the printed 2 or more lines string in Ruby?

Comment: Any statements such as `gets` would be executed first, in order to have values for the interpolation.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want my console to print 2 lines i.e. 1st line (Input 1: ) and in 2nd line (Input 2: ). then I want input prompt (gets) in front of my 1st line (Input 1: ).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly from your question, but I think this is what you are after:

[image]

This solution uses something called [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), which are "magic" sequences of characters you can use to control the terminal. You can do a variety of things with them, most commonly change output colour, but here we're using them to [move the cursor around](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html).

This works on my Mac, and should work on Linux - I'm not sure if this will work on Windows, you may have to [enable ANSI escape sequences manually](https://superuser.com/a/1050078/543418).

The general approach is:

1. Print the prompts
2. Move the cursor up to the line of the first prompt
3. Move the cursor forward to the end of that prompt
4. Accept input with `gets`
5. Move the cursor forward to the end of the second prompt
6. Accept input again

Here's a test script I wrote to do this, with enough comments to hopefully explain what is going on. I've changed the prompts from your original question so that they each have different lengths, to test that this solution can handle that.

```rb
prompt_1 = "First Input:"
prompt_2 = "Another Input:"

print "#{prompt_1}\n#{prompt_2}"

# Move the cursor back up to the line with the first prompt on
print "\033[1A"

# Move the cursor back to the start of the line, so we know we're in column zero
# Then move it to after the prompt
print "\033[1000D"
print "\033[#{prompt_1.length + 1}C"

# Get input
first_number = gets

# Hitting Enter after `gets` will have moved us to the next line already
# Move the cursor to the end of the second prompt
print "\033[1000D"
print "\033[#{prompt_2.length + 1}C"

# Get input again
second_number = gets

# Print output
puts "Addition is: #{first_number.strip.to_i + second_number.strip.to_i}"
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I am amazed by your solution and expertise. I was also thinking about cursor movement. You have gone over my expectation. Now I can manipulate it in my own way. :D

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it's working fine on Windows 10.